# Single Facebook App multiple Client Facebook Page Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a Facebook Application which will be used as a Facebook Tab Page. My problem is that I am unable to get the page id.

I want to use this single application for multiple Facebook Page Tabs but the content will vary based on the Page Id.

The code I am trying to use to get the signed_request is using the JavaScript SDK.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `signed_request` parameter, which is passed on to your URL.

The easiest solution is to use the PHP SDK. It offers a function called "getSignedRequest": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest

Those are the fields of the `signed_request` parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

If you don´t want to use the PHP, you need to parse the parameter on your own. Check out this link for more information and search for "Parsing the Signed Request": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games

Edit: you will not get the correct signed_request using the JavaScript SDK. Use PHP (or your server language) for this.

Comment: I am receiving the signed_request but only for the person who is an admin of the page, I just need the page id for whoever is the user irrespective of they like the page, for other users I am getting that they have not authorized my application. I am a little confused here. BTW Thank you @luschn

Comment: check out the settings, is your app public?

Comment: check out the tab "status & review" in the app settings: "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"

Comment: Your suggestion did not work making the page tab application public does not help and I still dont get the signed_request the response I get is authResponse: undefined, status: "not_authorized", I am getting this information for FB.getLoginStatus() using the JS SDK, I think I am wrong in using that, I dont want the page visitor to authorize my app I dont even need any of their information, I just need the page id they visit if my app is loaded

Comment: yeah, just as we discussed on facebook, you are obviously using the js sdk. you don´t need to authorize any user though.

Comment: my suggestion is 100% correct, did you really use PHP (or another server side language) to get signed_request, as i´ve answered?

Comment: I am trying with the post variable but it seems to be empty, I am using Yii framework for my application

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that the URL added in the Facebook page tab settings was getting redirected as it did not have a "/"; there was a redirect for SEO added and the URL in the Facebook APP sittings did not have the "/".

So as it was getting redirected Facebook sent the POST variable but we have not handled it. Now it is fixed.

Special thanks to @luschn and @Fran Barbero for all your efforts in this.